# LIBGDX: hit() method not called when a class extends scene2d.Stage

Tags: java, libgdx, extends, stage, hit

Here is the code that is confusing me. I might be missing something here but couldn't figure it out.

```
public class TStage extends Stage {

    public TStage(float width, float height, boolean stretch) {
        super(width, height, stretch);
    }

    @Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y) {
        Gdx.app.debug("HUNT", "in hit of TStage");
        return super.hit(x, y);
    }
}

public class TActor extends Actor {

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        // draw something here
    }

    @Override
    public Actor hit(float x, float y) {
        Gdx.app.debug("HUNT", "in hit of TActor");
        return null;
    }
}

    /* Code to set stage*/

    TStage stage = new TStage(Hunt.GAME_WIDTH, Hunt.GAME_HEIGHT, false);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    TActor actor1 = new TActor();
    stage.addActor(tactor);
```

when I touch the screen

output:

```
in hit of TActor
```

what I am expecting:

```
in hit of TStage  
in hit of TActor
```

[edit]
I add following code to TStage class

```
@Override
    public Actor touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.debug("HUNT", "in touchDown of TStage");
        return super.touchDown(x, y, pointer, button);
    }
```

Now the output is:

```
in touchDown of TStage  
in hit of TActor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some confusion about which method does what.

The method `hit()` returns the actor that is at those coordinates. The method you want is `touchDown()`. There's almost no information in the javadocs, so read this [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/scene2d#Is_anybody_listening?_Time_for_some_action!). You'll see that `TActor.hit()` is being called because that's how `Stage.touchDown()` finds the `Actor` that is at those coordinates.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added your suggestion along with output. Seems like that is the way to go.